# apache2 - security concern - no virtual host for specific domain

Tags: security, dns, apache2, virtualhost

Can it be dangerous to let domains linked to your apache2 without virtualhost to catch them ? Is it possible to configure apache to reject unknown domains ?

ex: domain is not referenced in a virtual host, therefore when apache2 answer to it, it takes the first virtualhost referenced on the server.
the same way, when we enter the ip address of the server, the first VH is taken to answer to the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally I would not consider it "dangerous", it more comes down to how do you want your server to behave. Personally, unless there is a reason not to do so, I always block unknown domains.

Apache can reject undefined domains by simply putting "catch all" domain at the top of the virtual hosts configuration file (or, in case you are using multiple conf files, in the alphabetically first file), and configuring that domain to unconditionally respond with 403 (or you can configure any other respond you find suitable):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName default
  RewriteRule ^ - [F]             
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  # ...             
</VirtualHost>
```